# Is there a way to make my PS3 load external drive's file faster

Tags: ps3

I mean it seems to load 1 folder at a time based on the date of creation so older folders are loaded first and recent ones at last.

Is there a way to load folders/files faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this would involve fundamentally changing the way the PS3 loads files. It is only something Sony can do.

If you want faster performace however you could install a hard disk with a higher RPM or you could splash out on an SSD